# Appengine users and admins - render template elements depending on user type

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, jinja2, google-identity

I am using the Google Identity platform for Python and I have two types of users - Provider and Consultant. Both will have an account in the Google Apps domain.

In order to separate my app workflows I think

- Provider should be a regular user
- Consultant should be an admin user

Admin users are discussed here:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/users/adminusers

I have a basic understanding that `is_current_user_admin()` provides a test if the current user is of type admin (and therefore a consultant in my app).

There are things I wish to display on particular pages differently depending on the user type.

For example how would I display the "Insert Assessment" link only to the admin in the following dropdown menu, and not to the non-admin users:

```
<div class="btn-group pull-right">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Consult Actions</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
  <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Edit Consult</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cancel Consult</a>
  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/schedule/insert-assessment?key={{consult.key.urlsafe()}}">Insert Assessment</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:** define admin variable ...?

```
def get(self):
        consult_key = ndb.Key(urlsafe=self.request.get('key'))
        consult = consult_key.get()
        # assessment and consult have the same key ID
        assessment = Assessments.get_by_id(consult_key.id())
        template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('/templates/view-consult.html')
        template_values = {
        'consult': consult,
        'assessment': assessment
        'admin': user is not None and user.is_current_user_admin()
        }
        self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem that divides into two separate subproblems: How do you display text in a template conditionally, and how do you tell if the current user is an admin.

The first problem is solved with the `{% if %}` tag. E.g, by

```
{% if admin %}
<div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="/schedule/insert-assessment?key={{consult.key.urlsafe()}}">Insert Assessment</a>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

The second problem is how to set the value of the `admin` variable. For that you can borrow code on the page you linked to, and use something like

```
'admin': user is not None and user.is_current_user_admin()
```

when you render the template.

Comment: Great ... so should I declare that 'admin' variable in the template_values dictionary I pass to the jinja template?  As in edit above?

Comment: That worked perfectly Dave, just note though that you missed the s in users : ie users.is_current_user_admin(). But good answer :)

Comment: I meant `user`, on the assumption that you would have done `user = users.get_current_user()` above that in the code.